# Running dblink from jpa

Tags: java, jpa, jboss, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

using Jboss5.1.x, EJB3.0, JPA.

Is there a way of running a query with DBLINK using JPA technology? Tried to find some information in the net, maybe with nativeQuery? anyone has any sample or experience with that?

thanks,

ray.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with DBLINK unless you mean dblink as a means of connecting a db with another db (like PostgreSQL.dblink). If so, you can use stored procedures from JPA (and native sql of course). JPQL is not capable of expressing what you want (if you want what I think you want).

Comment: Yes.. i want exactly what you said.. could you pass same example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used dblink call as I would use in JDBC, using NativeQuery